# Shall I use grad.zero_() in PyTorch with or without gradient tracking?

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd

I'm quite new to PyTorch, and I have a question about zeroing the gradients after an epoch. Suppose I have the following training loop:

```
for epoch in range(n_iters):
  y_hat = forward(X)
  l = loss(y, y_hat)
  with torch.no_grad():
    l.backward()
    w -= lr * w.grad
```

It is clear that in order not to have the gradients accumulated I need to zero the `.grad` attribute of `w`. However, I'm unsure about where to call `w.grad.zero_()`. I both found on internet tutorials where it was called in the `no_grad()` section and also where it was called out of it. So I tested them and they both worked fine for a simple linear regression.
Is any difference between the two? If there is, which is better to use?

Comment: Also I saw in some codes that they called `backward()` outside of `no_grad()` especially when using built-in optimizers. Does it have more computational cost doing so? I read that using `no_grad()` whenever gradient tracking not needed makes the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet that doesn't really matter. The underscore in the name of `zero_()` means it is an inplace function, and since `w.grad.requires_grad == False` we know that there won't be any gradient computation *with respect to* `w.grad` happening anyway. The only important thing is that it happens before the `loss.backward()` call.

I would recommend though to use different names for your loss function and the actuall loss tensor it computes, otherwise you're overwriting one with the other.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have added the definition of `w`. I used `requires_grad=True` because I want to optimize it.

Comment: Right `w` itself does need a gradient computation, but it's gradient `w.grad` is a different tensor from `w`, and `w.grad` doesn't need a gradient computation!